# Am I breaking the performance and use of a recycler view?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-recyclerview, android-linearlayout

So we are supposed to use the recycler view when we want to show a large list of elements.
The benefit of that is that views are re-used so we don't inflate each view in the list and keep them in memory and just keep in memory those that are displayed in the screen recycling the rest.
But what if the recycled view is itself a "mini" list?
I.e. for each item recycled we change its structure by removing all child views and adding new child views?
Is that defeating the whole idea of using a recycled list?
Example in question (`itemInRecycler` is a vertical `LinearLayout` that is passed to the recycler view holder):

```
itemInRecycler.removeAllViews();  
for(element: elements) {  
   CustomView view = inflate();  
   view.setDisplayData(element);  
   itemInRecycler.addView(view);  
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is that defeating the whole idea of using a recycled list?

It depends on how much of the whole `itemView` the sub-list is. If the sub-list is the only thing you're displaying, then yes, you're defeating a large portion of the performance gains. You're still inflating views every time you bind the `ViewHolder`, and that's one of the things you try to avoid when using RecyclerView.

It also depends on how large the sub-list is. If it's only three elements at most, then the cost is diminished. If the sublist is hundreds of items, then the cost is large.

One option is to use a sub-RecyclerView instead of a LinearLayout, and to connect each sub-RecyclerView to the same [shared `RecycledViewPool`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.RecycledViewPool). This way you get all the benefits of RecyclerView vs a scrollable LinearLayout, but even better because each sub-RecyclerView can take ViewHolders from the others.

If that's a little too heavy-handed for you, you could potentially just optimize the code you've already written. Instead of clearing the list each time and then re-inflating the correct number of views, you could re-use existing views (and only create new ones if there aren't enough) and remove the extra views if there are too many.

```
int i = 0;

// reuse existing views
for (; i < elements.size() && i < itemInRecycler.getChildCount(); i++) {
    Element element = elements.get(i);
    CustomView view = (CustomView) itemInRecycler.getChildAt(i);
    view.setDisplayData(element);
}

// create new views if there weren't enough to reuse
for (; i < elements.size(); i++) {
    Element element = elements.get(i);
    CustomView view = inflate();
    view.setDisplayData(element);
    itemInRecycler.addView(view);
}

// remove any extras after we've reused everything
int viewsToRemove = itemInRecycler.getChildCount() - i;

if (viewsToRemove > 0) {
    itemInRecycler.removeViews(i, viewsToRemove);
}
```

In a world where the `elements` collection always has between five and seven elements, say, this approach will make sure that you're always re-using the first five `CustomView`s, and then only inflating or removing 0-2 extra `CustomView`s.

Comment: This set of `for` loops is based off of the Android implementation for `Parcel.readTypedList()`, which similarly re-uses an existing list, only growing or shrinking its size as necessary: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/27f592d/core/java/android/os/Parcel.java#1796

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. You are right this "sublist" is most of what is displayed for each item. Right now the elements are not more than 4 but then it means that the solution won't scale if for example more data are loaded. 1) could you please share some code about the sub-recycler view you mentioned because I didn't understand how this is done? 2) If I understand correctly the approach of keeping some children and removing the extra and vice-versa won't scale also for list with varying items e.g. item with 2 sublists and item with 20? Also won't scale for a list with lots of data?

Comment: Re (2): the "cost" you're trying to avoid when binding ViewHolders is mostly the cost of inflating views, and a little bit the cost of doing view lookups with `findViewByid()`. The "reuse what views you can" approach I mention tries to reduce the cost of inflating views, but yes, it is somewhat limited. If half of your viewholders have two items and half have twenty, you'll find yourself inflating 18 views pretty often. But if half have 100 views and half have 101 views, then you'll find that you only inflate one view, and that's not so bad.

Comment: Re (1): I think that's a little outside the scope of an answer (it's more like a blog post). But basically the steps are... One: you'd create a single `RecycledViewPool`. Two: in `onCreateViewHolder()` you'd inflate a view holding a `RecyclerView` instead of a `LinearLayout`, and you'd call `setRecycledViewPool(sharedPool)` on that. Three: in `onCreateViewHolder()` set up an `Adapter` for your RecyclerView that worked with `Element` objects. Four: in `onBindViewHolder()` set the Adapter's elements and call `notifyDataSetChanged()`

Comment: It's a little light, but this blog post talks about it a bit: https://proandroiddev.com/optimizing-nested-recyclerview-a9b7830a4ba7

Comment: If the case was for half of the views to have 100 sub-items and half 101, why would I not just create a static linear layout in XML, inflate that and hide/show the last item?